# I've managed to break my terminal, (iTerm2(b17), ZSH, OSX10.6.6)

Tags: terminal, iterm

I'm migrating to a shiny new laptop (yay) unfortunately I've manually set up my iTerm to match the old machine, but something is not right (not yay).

I'm experiencing

- using `xterm-256color` doesn't give the full colour set for say, vim.
- applications like `vim` dont clear out of the scrollback when exited.
- my <kbd>↖ home</kbd> and <kbd>↘ end</kbd> keys are completely broken and I can't seem to Google a solution
- my <kbd>⌫ backspace</kbd> key doesn't delete backwards, it adds a 'space' and prevents further input until `^C`.

Here is my [.zshrc](http://paste2.org/p/1302831) and my [.profile](http://paste2.org/p/1302922). I dont have an `.inputrc`.

Here are my keyboard settings for iTerm2:

[image: screenshot20110315at801.png]

[image: screenshot20110315at801.png]

I'm fairly sure i've broken something between `$TERM`, iTerm2's keyboard settings and my `.zshrc`, but I'm simply not competent enough to debug it. As far as I can tell, my settings are identical to my old laptop, which works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that xterm-256color does not work correctly unless you have xcode installed.

Comment: Apparently, the terminfo files for xterm-256color and several others are in the Xcode installer instead of the system installer for 10.6. You should find that in Mac OS X Lion 10.7 these files are installed with the system.